# preg_replace constant in string PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, constants

I have defined constant:

```
defined('site_name') OR define('site_name', 'Ses');
```

How I can replace variables in a string with constants?

```
defined('site_name') OR define('site_name', 'Ses');
$string = 'Some string with {site_name} constant';

$result = preg_replace("/{.*?}/", CONSTANT, $string);
```

Comment: Please, add some your tries. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the constant using a capture group`()`, use it in a callback and access the constant with the string name using `constant`:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/{(.*?)}/",
                                function($m) {
                                    return constant($m[1]);
                                }, $string);
```

Comment: I got an error `Message:  Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`